# Representations of semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $L$ a Lie algebra and $V$ a representation of $L$. We define
$$ V^{L}:= \{ v \in V \, | \, xv=0, \, \forall x \in L \} $$
and $V_{L}:=V/LV$. Let $\pi: L \rightarrow V_{L}$ be the quotient omomorphism. If $L$ is semisimple and $dim(V) < \infty$ then the restriction of $\pi$ to $V^{L}$ is an isomorphism. In order to prove this we can prove injectivity and surjectivity. Injectivity: Using Weyl theorem $V$ is completely reducible because of semisimplicity of $L$ and dim$(V)<\infty$. So
$$V=V^L\oplus W$$
with $W$ complemetar subrepresentation. In order to prove injectivity of $\pi_{|_{V^L}}$ we consider not null $v\in V^L$. If $\pi(v)=0$ we must have $v=x.w$ for $x\in L$ and $w \in W$. $W$ is a subrepresentation so $x.w\in W$. And it is not possible. How can I prove the surjectivity?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the map to be from $V$ to $V_L$. As in your proof of injectivity, write $V = V_L \oplus W$ and note that the map $\pi$ is now simply the map given by $(v,w)\mapsto v$ for $v\in V_L$ and $w\in W$. It is now clear that the map is surjective when restricted to $V_L$ since any element $v\in V_L$ is the image of $(v,0)$ which is how we identify an element of $V_L$ in $V$.